# Ignore files in remote repo only?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm pretty sure I can't do this, as my local repo is presumably intended to be maintained as a clone of the remote repo and thus without any differences.

But I would like to have some files which are tracked in my local repo, but NOT tracked in the remote (Bitbucket) repo I push to.

I and a colleague are working on some source code, which is tracked, but ideally, I would like to be able to track my IDE project files as well, for example, I could clone my local repo and have a fully working directory but my IDE project files are not going to be the same as my colleague's, so I wouldn't want those to be pushed to the remote repo.

Given that this must be a pretty common requirement, what do people do to achieve this kind of thing?

Comment: There is no way to do that the way you want. You can create a new local branch in your repository, add your config files, push it to the remote and then always keep it in sync with the stable branch.

Comment: Maybe this depends on the IDE. But with Qt for instance, I push the .pro file which is common for all users. Opening the .pro file in QtCreator then generates a .pro.user file or similar, which is only for the user and should not be pushed.

Comment: The trick here is to realize that Git stores (and pushes and fetches) *commits*, not *files*. It's true that a commit *contains* files—in fact, each commit has a complete snapshot of *every* file—so the effect is similar. But you either have a commit (all the files) or don't have it (none of the files). There's no way to just have a few files, unless that commit's snapshot is just those few files. If you `git checkout` a snapshot that has just 2 or 3 files, that's all you have in the checkout: those 2 or 3 files.

Comment: Hence, while you can get what you want, it's not really what you want, if you take my meaning. :-) If you do want to commit snapshots of configurations, I'd recommend putting them into a separate Git repository.

Answer (score -1):

> I and a colleague are working on some source code, which is tracked, but ideally, I would like to be able to track my IDE project files as well, for example, I could clone my local repo and have a fully working directory **but my IDE project files are not going to be the same as my colleague's, so I wouldn't want those to be pushed to the remote repo**.

---

## Yep you can do it.

---

You can "tell" git to ignore your local changes of specific files.

#### The flow:

- Clone the repo and get the required content
- "Tell" git to ignore your local changes
- Continue with push/pull as usual.

**Note**
If you will have conflicts in the file you will need to thing what you want to do.

---

#### "Tell" git to ignore your local changes

#### `--[no-]assume-unchanged`

> When this flag is specified, **the object names recorded for the paths are not updated.**
>
> Instead, this option sets/unsets the "assume unchanged" bit for the paths.
>
> When the "assume unchanged" bit is on, the user promises not to change the file and allows **Git to assume that the working tree file matches what is recorded in the index.** If you want to change the working tree file, you need to unset the bit to tell Git. This is sometimes helpful when working with a big project on a filesystem that has very slow lstat(2) system call (e.g. cifs).
>
> Git will fail (gracefully) in case it needs to modify this file in the index e.g. when merging in a commit; thus, in case the assumed-untracked file is changed upstream, you will need to handle the situation manually.

[image]